# Avoid Select options to be duplicated in vuejs

Tags: vuejs2

I am getting duplicate options in a multi select dropdown (select2).
I have a parent and a child select dropdowns. Everytime I select child option its parent gets populated too.
Eg : With Category & Subcategory dropdowns if I select 2 subcat from same category, its category gets populated twice.

```html
<select style="width: 100%" multiple v-model="item.host_groups" v-select2 class="form-control select2" v-bind:id="'tmp_hostgroup_'+index" >
<option v-for=" option in hosts.host_mapping" v-if="item.hosts.includes(option.host_name)" :value="option.host_group" :key="option.host_group">@{{ option.host_group }}</option>
</select>
```

I have binded the value but still, see duplicates.

As in the screenshot below everytime I select Item that belong to same group the Item Group gets selected multiple times ending up with duplicates (AA in pic)

[image]

I also have onchange of select2

```
     directives: {
                select2: {
                    inserted: function(el) {
                        $(el).select2({
                            width: 'resolve',
                            allowClear: true,
                        }).on('select2:select', function() {
                            const event = new Event('change', {bubbles : true, cancelable: true}) ;
                            el.dispatchEvent(event);
                        });
                    }
                },
```

Comment: Mind sharing the "duplicates"?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have tried that too but that's not working. Please see edited code.